# CASE statement inside EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, exists

I need to create a query which looks like this:

> SELECT attr 
>   FROM SomeTable B 
>   WHERE EXISTS 
>     
>   (CASE WHEN B.some_attr = 0   
>  
>          
>   THEN (SELECT x FROM C WHERE B.z = z)   
>      
>   WHEN B.some_attr = 1   
>         
>   THEN (SELECT x FROM D WHERE B.z = x)  
>     
>   END)

But SQL Server refuses to execute this bringing some syntax error. 
How can I modify this query to make it work?

**EDIT:** I'm adding the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'. 
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'. 
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: 'Some syntax error' would be a big help to everyone who is willing to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A 
FROM B 
WHERE 
     CASE 
     WHEN B.some_attr = 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT x FROM C WHERE B.z = z) THEN 1
     WHEN B.some_attr = 1 AND EXISTS(SELECT x FROM D WHERE B.z = x) THEN 1
     END = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A
FROM B
WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN B.some_attr = 0
          THEN (SELECT x FROM C WHERE B.z = z)
          WHEN B.some_attr = 1
          THEN (SELECT x FROM D WHERE B.z = x)
     END) is not null
```

This assumes the subqueries return one row.  If not, just put in max(x) rather than x.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work as well:

```
SELECT attr 
FROM SomeTable B 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM C WHERE B.some_attr = 0 AND B.z = z UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 FROM D WHERE B.some_attr = 1 AND B.z = x
)
```